# Loop too fast for read.csv

Tags: r, for-loop, read.csv

I wrote a loop that reads the csv files and rbind them.

```
vec1 = c(0,1,3,5,9)
vec2 = c("mom", "dad")
c = data.frame()

for(i in length(vec1))
{
  for (j in length(vec2))
  {
    dir = paste("../data/year ", vec1[i], "/ff_", vec2[j], "_cb", vec1[i], ".csv", sep="")
    a = read.csv(dir)
    Sys.sleep(3)
    c = rbind(c,a)

  }

}
```

However, when I try to execute it, only the result from the last iteration is there. (i.e. `a` has the value from the last iteration, and `c` is the same as `a`).

I though this is because the loop is too fast, that it does not wait for read.csv to finish before going to the next. Therefore, I put a sys.sleep(3) in there.

However, the same problem persists. Moreover, I was able to set `i`, `j` manually to complete this task, so the syntax should be correct, but I don't know what the problem is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your loops are incorrect.  `for(i in length(vec1))` will only perform one iteration.  The correct format is:  `for(i in 1:length(vec1))`
For example try this:

```
vec1 = c(0,1,3,5,9)
vec2 = c("mom", "dad")
for(i in 1:length(vec1))
{
  for (j in 1:length(vec2))
  {
    print(paste(i, j))   
  }  
}
```

Then repeat the example with your statements.

Comment: That was an embarrassing mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As [Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43533092/271616) noted in their answer, your loops are incorrect. While their answer is correct, it is better to use `seq_along` to avoid problems if `vec1` or `vec2` are zero-length vectors.  For example:

```
vec1 <- integer()
vec2 <- c("mom", "dad")

for(i in 1:length(vec1))
{
  for (j in 1:length(vec2))
  {
    print(paste(vec1[i], vec2[j]))
  }
}
#[1] "NA mom"
#[1] "NA dad"
#[1] " mom"
#[1] " dad"
```

When you really wanted no iterations:

```
for(i in seq_along(vec1))
{
  for (j in seq_along(vec2))
  {
    print(paste(vec1[i], vec2[j]))
  }
}
```

In this specific case, you don't even need an integer iterator. You can simply loop over the vector elements themselves.

```
vec1 <- c(0, 1)
vec2 <- c("mom", "dad")

for(v1 in vec1)
{
  for (v2 in vec2)
  {
    print(paste(v1, v2))
  }
}
# [1] "0 mom"
# [1] "0 dad"
# [1] "1 mom"
# [1] "1 dad"
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and tips. But I can only accept one answer >.>. Sorry about that.